# RestEasy - Unable to invoke request - RESTEASY004655 - SSL Exception

Tags: java, ssl, resteasy

I am trying to create client with rest easy and disabling SSL using disableTrustManager. But It is not working . I am getting

> Unable to invoke request - RESTEASY004655

Here is the client creation code

```
private Client client = new ResteasyClientBuilder()
                        .disableTrustManager()
                        .defaultProxy(proxyHost, proxyPort)
                        .build();
WebTarget webTarget = client.target("URL");
Response response = webTarget.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
                .post(Entity.entity(requestFileContent, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM));
```

Exception stacktrace

> javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: RESTEASY004655: Unable to invoke request
>    \n\tat org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.engines.ApacheHttpClient4Engine.invoke(ApacheHttpClient4Engine.java:289)\n\tat
>     org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocation.invoke(ClientInvocation.java:454)\n\tat 
>     org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocationBuilder.post(ClientInvocationBuilder.java:193)\n\tat 
>     com. .vertical.causes.kermit. Sample. SampleRequestSubmitter.submitRequestFile( SampleRequestSubmitter.java:59)\n\tat 
>     com. .vertical.causes.kermit. Sample. SampleUtil.upload SampleFile( SampleUtil.java:551)\n\tat 
>     com. .vertical.causes.kermit. Sample. SampleUtil.upload SampleEligibleClaims( SampleUtil.java:518)\n\tat 
>     com. .vertical.causes.kermit.CauseReadImpl.upload SampleEligibleClaims(CauseReadImpl.java:6130)\n\tat 
>     sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\n\tat 
>     sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)\n\tat 
>     sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\n\tat 
>     java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)\n\tat org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:140)\n\tat
>      org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:294)\n\tat 
>      org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:248)\n\tat
>       org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:235)\n\tat 
>       org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:402)\n\tat 
>       org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:209)\n\tat 
>       org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:227)\n\tat
>        org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56)\n\tat 
>        org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:51)\n\tat 
>        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)\n\tat 
>        org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)\n\tat 
>        org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\n\tat 
>        org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)\n\tat 
>        org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\n\tat 
>        org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\n\tat 
>        com. .platform.service.rest.CoreContextFilter.doFilter(CoreContextFilter.java:75)\n\tat 
>        org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\n\tat
>         org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\n\tat
>          com. .raptor.web.filters.SSLApplicationFilter.doFilter(SSLApplicationFilter.java:57)\n\tat 
>          org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\n\tat 
>          org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\n\tat 
>          com. .raptor.web.filters.SSLValidateInternalsFilter.doFilter(SSLValidateInternalsFilter.java:70)\n\tat 
>          org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\n\tat 
>          org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\n\tat 
>          com. .platform.service.rest.logging.OuterTransactionCalFilter.doFilter(OuterTransactionCalFilter.java:124)\n\tat
>           org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\n\tat
>            org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\n\tat 
>            org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)\n\tat 
>            org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.Appli

I want to skip SSL verification for this client. Can someone help me.

From restEasy document

> /**
>       * Disable trust management and hostname verification.  *NOTE* this is a security
>       * hole, so only set this option if you cannot or do not want to verify the identity of the
>       * host you are communicating with.
>       */
>      public ResteasyClientBuilder disableTrustManager()

Comment: Please provide full stacktrace

Comment: Updated @YuriyAlevohin